# extract two columns and add at a specific location to another file that is already full of columns

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a file where I want to extract two columns and add at a specific location to another file that is already full of columns.

Could I cat file 1 and make it a variable and then cat file 2 and make it a variable and then combine variables with export and awk? Someone helped me before with single lines of text in this manner, but I don't know if it applies to whole files.

example:

## Input file 1

```
Group F3D0 F3D1 F3D9 F3D     
Otu01 1627 1935 8335 241
```

## Input file 2

```
oi1 oi2    
lk8 po8
```

## Output file

```
oi1 oi2 Group F3D0 F3D1 F3D9 F3D     
lk8 po8 Otu01 1627 1935 8335 241
```

Comment: It seems like you don't need any more that `paste -d ' ' file2 file1` in this case

Comment: fair enough, but what if the addition of file 2 needed to go to a specific column location (rather than just the start of file 1), how do you code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you show, all you really need is

```
paste -d ' ' file2 file1
```

You an do pretty much whatever you want order-wise using `cut` and `paste` (and some shell process substitution) e.g. to output the first two columns of `file1` followed by the second column of `file2` followed by the remainder of `file1` and finally the first column of `file2` you could do

```
paste -d ' ' <(cut -d ' ' -f 1,2 file1) <(cut -d ' ' -f 2 file2) <(cut -d ' ' -f 3- file1) <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 file2)
```

Or (perhaps more efficiently) you could paste the two files together as-is and pipe the result to `awk` to select specific columns in a specific order:

```
paste -d ' ' file1 file2 | awk '{print $1, $2, $NF, $3, $4, $5, $(NF-1)}'
```

or (if you prefer), with `perl`

```
paste -d ' ' file1 file2 | 
  perl -alne 'print join " ", @F[0,1],@F[6],@F[2..4],@F[5]'
```

Comment: sweet answer thanks, can't even begin to tell you how handy that explanation is for me in understanding and improving my text processing.